# Are gems folder specific?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have an old Ruby on Rails project that I work on as a hobby, but I have never implemented Rspec testing.

Now I would like to do so, so I am reading the fine book 'Effective Testing with Rspec 3'. I would assume the techniques used in the Rspec book and the rspec gem are applicable to the rspec-rails gem, because I got the rspec book from rspec.info, which only offers documentation for rspec-rails and its dependencies. I assume rspec-rails auto-creates the sub folders and files in a RoR project etc. Which one I'm going to use to implement the tests I'm not sure at this point.

Anyway I apparently have rspec installed in my old hobby PROJECT directory (rspec -v from the project directory)

```
3.5.4
```

and rspec-rails is also a gem inside the project Gemfile (an outdated version, but current to the time of writing the book), which is also installed along with rspec, according to gem list --local, but I also get 'command not found' with rspec-rails -v from within the old project directory.

So I have created a new folder called rspectest, in which I will use to implement the examples and instructions in the book. However, following the instructions in Chapter 1:

```
$ gem install rspec -v 3.6.0
Successfully installed rspec-support-3.6.0
Successfully installed rspec-core-3.6.0
Successfully installed diff-lcs-1.3
Successfully installed rspec-expectations-3.6.0
Successfully installed rspec-mocks-3.6.0
Successfully installed rspec-3.6.0
6 gems installed
```

I have attempted to similarily install rspec in my new rspectest folder, but I get error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rspec' (= 3.5.4) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: r_spec
```

The reason I ask is because on page 7 it asks to run the command rspec from the project directory, to see the results of an example, and I get:

```
Command 'rspec' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ruby-rspec-core
```

So I have to assume this command will allow access to the gem from this particular new rspec testing folder only, if typed from within the directory (?):

```
sudo apt install ruby-rspec-core
```

And will not mess with the gems of different project folders, which I assume is the point of gemfile etc, in case different versions of gems are installed locally.

... guess I about figured that one out, my apologies. I'll delete this unless the above command doesn't work. EDIT: pending answers to these questions:

1. Are all folders independent of each other, generally, as far as gems and their accessibility?
2. Do I need bundle to install a gem in a particular folder? I assume not since gem install is a thing, and would require setting up a Rails project, which I could do, but it's literally example #1 in the book.
3. If I go sudo apt install ruby-rspec-core in a random folder (and it installs another version or something weird), is that going to affect my old project folder?

I also assume not, but it'd be nice to clarify why the book examples aren't working off the bat. I dislike having to reinstall the repo or having to wipe the drive when i start experimenting, especially when it's only on page 4

Comment: The `rspec` gem is a _meta-gem_ used to easily install the actual gems `rspec-core`, `rspec-expectations` and `rspec-mocks`. It doesn't itself have a version 3.5.4, hence the error (see https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec/versions). You install the `rspec` meta-gem in version 3.5.0 via `gem install rspec -v 3.5.0` and it will install the actual gems (`rspec-core`, `rspec-expectations` and `rspec-mocks`) using their highest-released 3.5.x versions which happens to be 3.5.4.

Comment: Aside from the gem version problem, rspec should already be available because you installed it for the other project. Make sure that you are running the same Ruby version in both projects (maybe there's a ruby version manager involved). Running `gem environment` in both project directories should help to identify the problem – it shows the current Ruby version and the installations paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is a bit confusing but I'll just give you a general overview of how gems are managed on your machine.

Typically in a rails project there is a Gemfile that defines your ruby version as well as the gems you need for your projects. Sometimes they will have specific version specified as well `'gem 'aws-ses-v4', '~> 0.8.1'`

Also it is good practice to use something like either rvm or rbenv(my preference) to handle ruby management. This is useful for having multiple versions of ruby on your computer. For rbenv you will have a .ruby-version file that you use to set the ruby version and anytime you are in that project directory and run a command rbenv will check that file to determine which ruby version its using and where it should look to find gems, etc.

Now if you aren't using that you are going to need to manually set what version of ruby you are using in terminal and what I'm suspecting you have happening is that you have multiple ruby versions and one of which has rspec installed while the other doesn't.

You should never really need to manually run gem install besides for bundler, and then use a Gemfile and bundle install for everything else.

If you are manually running the gem install command its going to drop the gem inside of the your local directory for the ruby version you are currently using. This will be different based of what kind of computer you are using. For me using rbenv its `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems` but not overly sure where it is by default.

Comment: I appreciate that. I'm using linux cinnamon mint 19.3, somewhat older. I've ascertained from my original post that my PROJECT folder gems are protected by the Rails gemfile, and installing/using different version gems won't affect it. I'm still confused on why an installed gem in a rails folder isn't accessible from another folder. I do have rvm, but only one version of ruby

Comment: are all folders independent of each other, generally, as far as gems and their accessibility? Do I need bundle to install a gem in a particular folder?  If I go sudo apt install ruby-rspec-core in a random folder (and it installs another version or something weird), is that going to affect my old project folder?  i assume not, but it'd be nice to clarify why the book examples aren't working

Comment: Where ever you run the gem install command from its going to install that gem in the gems folder for the ruby version you are currently using. And you should have access to them regardless of what directory you are currently in.

This does get a bit weird if you are using rvm some places and trying to bypass it others. Did you use rvm install when you installed your ruby version? Because using rvm installs it in a different place.

Comment: For instance if you just use homebrew or something to install a ruby version its gonna just put it in /usr/bin/ruby or something like that. But when you use rvm install it will go to /usr/.rvm/ruby instead.(I just made these directories up to get the idea across)

So if you are in some random directory and run gem install and then change to a project directory that is managed by rvm, rvm is going to expect that gem to be in its directory where as you installed it in a different place.

Running something like ```sudo apt install ruby-rspec-core``` will bypass rvm stuff.

Comment: I would add what you need to your gemfile and run bundle install

Comment: I did use RVM to install Ruby. So if I was a pro I'd have multiple ruby versions depending on the projects, and when working on one would install the gem, which would be availalbe only to the Ruby version. Got it.  I've only ever used one ruby version, set up with rvm, so any and all gems should be currently accessible from all folders, if i'm ready you right, but they are not.

Comment: so rvm allows me to bundle install gems inside a Rails project, but doesn't allow me to access the same gems outside the rails project? i can't run the examples in the book in a random folder because i used rvm to install ruby?

Comment: Yes if you are outside of a project that is setup with rvm you won't have access to those gems you installed while you were in that project directory. Because it won't know where they are supposed to be. I would just setup your hobby project to have rspec and use it to test what they are trying to have you try.

Comment: I appreciate that, thank you. Suppose another option would be to set up another Rails project specifically to complete the exercises in this book, but I will probably do it from within this previous project, as recommended. So for the record, if I hadn’t used rvm this wouldn’t be an issue and gems would be ruby version specific and accessible anywhere, and not project specific, and only accessible literally through Rails projects. Rvm is the only ruby installer with this unfortunate inconvenience.

Comment: ... pretty sweet that rspec rails was setting up rspec independently. rspec files already for 32 controllers and 55 models, prob saves at least an hour right there. ok, back to page 4